# How to specify the batch dimension in a conv2D layer with pyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 600x600 grayscale images, grouped in batches of 50 images by a dataloader.

My network has a convolution layer with 16 filters, followed by Maxpooling with 6x6 kernels, and then a Dense layer. The output of the conv2D should be `out_channels*width*height/maxpool_kernel_W/maxpool_kernel_H = 16*600*600/6/6 = 160000`, multiplied by the batch size, 50.

However when I try to do a forward pass I get the following error: `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (80000x100 and 160000x1000)`. I verified that the data is formatted correctly as `[batch,n_channels,width,height]` (so [50,1,600,600] in my case).

Logically the output should be a 50x160000 matrix, but apparently it is formatted as a 80000x100 matrix. It seems like torch is multiplying the matrices along the wrong dimensions. If anyone understands why, please help me understand too.

```
# get data (using a fake dataset generator)
dataset = FakeData(size=500, image_size= (1, 600, 600), transform=ToTensor())
training_data, test_data = random_split(dataset,[400,100])
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader  = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)

net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1,              
                out_channels=16,            
                kernel_size=5,                     
                padding=2,           
            ),
    nn.ReLU(),  
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=6),
    nn.Linear(160000, 1000),
    nn.ReLU(),
)

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3,)

epochs = 10
for i in range(epochs):
    for (x, _) in train_dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # make sure the data is in the right shape
        print(x.shape) # returns torch.Size([50, 1, 600, 600])

        # error happens here, at the first forward pass
        output = net(x)

        criterion = nn.MSELoss()
        loss = criterion(output, x)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect your model's inference layer by layer you would have noticed that the [`nn.MaxPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html) returns a 4D tensor shaped `(50, 16, 100, 100)`. There are different ways to reduce spatial dimensionality (flattening, average-pooling, max-pooling). For instance, if you want to flatten the spatial dimensions, this will result in a tensor of shape `(50, 16*100*100)`, *ie.* `(50, 160_000)` as you expected to have. This being said you are required to use a [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) layer.

```
net = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
                    nn.ReLU(),  
                    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=6),
                    nn.Flatten(),
                    nn.Linear(160000, 1000),
                    nn.ReLU())
```